# What is the brand of this rear rack?

Tags: identify-this-bike, rack, germany

I have a bike which was bought in Germany in 1995. It has a super nice steel rear rack which, after 25 years, has no wear marks besides some scratches in the paint. Does anyone know which brand this is?

[image: logo]

Comment: Not sure what that logo is. Guessing from the fact that it is a German brand, Tubus is the most popular German brand for cycle racks.

Comment: Its not the current tubus logo,. which is more like https://www.tubus.com/typo3conf/ext/tubus/Resources/Public/Images/logo.svg  Doesn't help that "logo" is one of their models.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! ... ah it's such a nice and solid rack! I wish I knew the manufacturer. I don't think it's Tubus. ... maybe it's simply from the good old times in which racks were robust and actually lasted even if they were from a noname brand ;-)

Comment: @Stücke: I’ve never seen a broken rack (even cheap and flimsy ones are surprisingly sturdy, considering how often adolescents transport people on them), usually it’s just the bolts which come loose because people don’t install with thread locker or sufficient torque.

Comment: I just experienced a situation in which a weld seam broke but I suppose you are right! ... it's extremely rare. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I'm not sure if @Stücke is still around, but I've guessed which way up the logo is meant to be (from the mudguard stays) and would like confirmation - not that I've matched any images.  A photo showing more of the rack might help; it actually looks a bit unusual

Comment: Looks like cast Aluminium, like Pletscher make.

Comment: Where in Germany was the bike bought?

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of the writing. It looks like it could be a stylized form of the lower-case "o" in Sütterlin Schrift (assuming the picture needs to be rotated ~ 90 degrees clockwise so the circle is sitting on top.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlin

Comment: @Tim it certainly does, but lower case would seem odd combined with Sütterlin. I don't recall very many German logos using lowercase, and only recent ones.

Comment: @JoeK I reckon anodised aluminium from the picture.  The logo looks cast but surely the bars aren't solid

Comment: @JoeK -The look is very similar to the [Pletscher Athlete System](https://www.pletscher.ch/index.php/products-de/carriers-de/system-carriers-de)! Mine is from the late 90s so maybe they've slightly changed the design since then? ... Actually, I even sent them an email with pictures and asked whether they produced my rack two decades ago but they never responded. Anyway ... if it is a Pletscher and they maintained the same quality I can highly recommend them ... :D

Comment: @Stücke It's not impossible that Pletscher made this with another brand mark or for your bicycle manufacturer. It is very hard to know for sure but the cast aluminium racks with those types of shapes are synonymous with Pletscher. It seems unlikely that it would be a clone from another country.

Comment: If you're still about, please try a magnet to see if it is steel.  The colour in your photo looks like cast aluminium, and I thing I can see a mould join line, or seam which also suggests a casting.  Weighing it might also help show if its exceptionally light and therefore aluminium, because steel tends to be heavy.   Finally, are you sure its painted ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a magnet at hand but it looks very similar to those of Pletscher which use aluminum die casting.